# Excel sum equal column values

Tags: excel

I want to sum the number of columns, in which the value from column D equals value from column F (D2=F2, D3=F3, D4=F4...), I know of the IF statement like

```
=SUM(IF(D2=F2;1;0))
```

but how do I loop through, from D2 to e.g. D103 and count if one equals another?

Comment: `for i=2 to 103`?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(D2:D103=F2:F103))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya `=SUM(D2:D103=F2:F103)` will always return 0, since there is no coercion on the Booleans.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I have O365 and I have never seen an array of Booleans being passed to `SUM` as resulting in anything over than zero. Kindly share a screenshot somehow, since if what you say is true then that is a huge development in Excel functionality.

Comment: No no sorry, I agree with you, but I dont remember where I used it, worked for me, i am removing my comment now.